# Not able to run react native in windows

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, sdk

**Not able to run react native in windows**

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 in

C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 23 in

C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 23 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

**but i tried add licences forder to sdk path it didnt worked.i update the all of my skd platform and sdk tools.but still im getting this error.how can i fix this.**

Answer (score 0):

If you start the Android Studio IDE, it will prompt you to agree to the license agreement. Once you accept, this error should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the entire Android Studio and reinstall with the latest Android SDK platforms will probably do the trick. Also, please try using the `> sdkmanager --licenses` command.